# How to parse an XML node having key-value pair using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anyone help me to 
Filter all the record with event_id=100 and Get the top five devices with maximum duration (here the duration values are in xml format)

**the column/field names are,**

Server-Unique-Id
Request-Type
Event-Id
Timestamp
XML with tags of name and value
Device Id
Secondary Timestamp
**record in file are like :**

11001^1^100^2015-06-05 22:35:45.927^^0122648d-4352-4eec-9327-effae0c34ef2^2016060601

here is the code that i have written and stuck to get the values out of caseclass

```
object RecEventId100 extends App{


  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/home/hp/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2")
  System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:/home/hp/spark/spark-warehouse")

  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AvgAnsTime").master("local").getOrCreate()
  val data = spark.read.textFile("/home/hp/Veeresh_data/sparkScala programs/Set_up_Box/Set_Top_Box_Data_test.txt").rdd

  val result = data.filter{lines => {lines.split("\\^")(2).equals("100")}}

  val res = result .map{lines =>{val tokens = lines.split("\\^")
    (tokens(5),tokens(4))
  }}

  val parseXML = res.map{rec =>{
    val xml = XML.loadString(rec._2)
    (rec._1, xml)
  }}

  case class keyValCls (a : String, b : String)

  val getD = parseXML.map{line => {

    val items = line._2 \ "nv"
    val durationKey = items.map(i => i \ "@n")
    val durationVal = items.map(i => i \ "@v")
    val length = durationKey.length - 1

    for(len <- 0 to  length )
      if(durationKey(len).toString().equals("Duration")) {
        println("Inside Duration - "+durationKey(len)+ " Val - "+durationVal(len))
        val cc = keyValCls(durationVal(len).toString(), line._1))
        println("case class Duration - "+cc.a+ " case class deviceID - "+cc.b)

      }
    keyValCls
  }}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use case class and map after case class.

I have re-written a snippet in your code(map before case class)

```
val parseXML = res.map{rec =>{
    val xml = XML.loadString(rec._2)
    val v=((xml \ "nv").filter(node => (node \@ "n") == "Duration")) \@ "v"
    (rec._1, v)
  }}
```